# Why ol-layerswitcher latest version can't run in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, layer-switcher

I did try load ["ol-layerswitcher"](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher) in OpenLayers but It didn't work. Furthermore I tried run that through its examples in GitHub but it didn't show anything. Where is my mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=" LATIN1 ">
<head>
  <title>ol-Layerswitcher</title>
   <!-- Openlayers v6.3.1-->

    <link rel="stylesheet " href="../ol/css/ol.css ">
    <!-- ol-layerswitcher -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="../ol-layerswitcher/src/ol-layerswitcher.css " type="text/css "/>

    <style>

       #map{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75%;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>ol-layerswitcher</h1>
      <div id="map ">

      </div>
      <script src="../ol/build/ol.js "></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/ol-layerswitcher@3.6.0 "></script>
      <script src="../ol-layerswitcher/dist/ol-layerswitcher.js "></script>



      <script>
          (function() {
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                'title': 'Base maps',
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Group({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'Water color with labels',
                        // Setting the layers type to 'base' results
                        // in it having a radio button and only one
                        // base layer being visibile at a time
                        type: 'base',
                        // Setting combine to true causes sub-layers to be hidden
                        // in the layerswitcher, only the parent is shown
                        combine: true,
                        visible: false,
                        layers: [
                            new ol.layer.Tile({
                                source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                    layer: 'watercolor'
                                })
                            }),
                            new ol.layer.Tile({
                                source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                    layer: 'terrain-labels'
                                })
                            })
                        ]
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'Water color',
                        // Again set this layer as a base layer
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: false,
                        source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                            layer: 'watercolor'
                        })
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'OSM',
                        // Again set this layer as a base layer
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: true,
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    })
                ]
            }),
            new ol.layer.Group({
                // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                title: 'Overlays',
                // Adding a 'fold' property set to either 'open' or 'close' makes the group layer
                // collapsible
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Image({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'Countries',
                        source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                            ratio: 1,
                            params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                            url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Boundaries/Countries_December_2016_Boundaries/MapServer "
                        })
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Group({
                        // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                        title: 'Census',
                        fold: 'open',
                        layers: [
                            new ol.layer.Image({
                                // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                                title: 'Districts',
                                source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                                    ratio: 1,
                                    params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                                    url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Local_Authority_Districts_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer "
                                })
                            }),
                            new ol.layer.Image({
                                // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                                title: 'Wards',
                                visible: false,
                                source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                                    ratio: 1,
                                    params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                                    url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Wards_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer "
                                })
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([-0.92, 52.96], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 6
        })
    });

    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Légende', // Optional label for button
        groupSelectStyle: 'children' // Can be 'children' [default], 'group' or 'none'
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
    layerSwitcher.showPanel();

})();
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. My OS is Debian 10 x65
2. OpenLayers v6.3.1
3. Node v14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot verify your local links but you need to remove trailing spaces from some strings such as

```
<div id="map ">
```

and the ArcGIS URLs

If you are setting the map height to a percentage you must define the html and body style

```
<style>
   html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The LayerSwitcher object is no longer available in the new OpenLayers version.

However you can still add it from an external repository. The following code should work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=" LATIN1 ">
    <head>
        <title>ol-Layerswitcher</title>
        <!-- Openlayers v6.3.1-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css">
        <style>

               .map{
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 75%;
              }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>

        <!-- ol-layerswitcher -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ol-layerswitcher@3.5.0"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ol-layerswitcher@3.5.0/src/ol-layerswitcher.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>ol-layerswitcher</h1>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Group({
                            'title': 'Base maps',
                            layers: [
                                new ol.layer.Group({
                                    title: 'Water color with labels',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    combine: true,
                                    visible: false,
                                    layers: [
                                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                                layer: 'watercolor'
                                            })
                                        }),
                                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                                layer: 'terrain-labels'
                                            })
                                        })
                                    ]
                                }),
                                new ol.layer.Tile({
                                    title: 'Water color',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    visible: false,
                                    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                                        layer: 'watercolor'
                                    })
                                }),
                                new ol.layer.Tile({
                                    title: 'OSM',
                                    type: 'base',
                                    visible: true,
                                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                                })
                            ]
                        }),
                        new ol.layer.Group({
                            title: 'Overlays',
                            fold: 'open',
                            layers: [
                                new ol.layer.Image({
                                    title: 'Countries',
                                    source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                                        ratio: 1,
                                        params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                                        url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Boundaries/Countries_December_2016_Boundaries/MapServer "
                                    })
                                }),
                                new ol.layer.Group({
                                    title: 'Census',
                                    fold: 'open',
                                    layers: [
                                        new ol.layer.Image({
                                            title: 'Districts',
                                            source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                                                ratio: 1,
                                                params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                                                url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Local_Authority_Districts_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer "
                                            })
                                        }),
                                        new ol.layer.Image({
                                            title: 'Wards',
                                            visible: false,
                                            source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                                                ratio: 1,
                                                params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                                                url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Wards_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer "
                                            })
                                        })
                                    ]
                                })
                            ]
                        })
                    ],
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.transform([-0.92, 52.96], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                        zoom: 6
                    })
                });

            var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
                tipLabel: 'Légende',
                groupSelectStyle: 'children' 
            });
            map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
            layerSwitcher.showPanel();


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ohhh really, I didn't know, could you please tell me what 3rd party or even ol properties is best? exp: GeoExt3 or Layer Groups?

Comment: A built in layer switcher hasn't been available since version 2.  The walkermatt link in the question is a third party extension.